# INSERT via SELECT DISTINCT but skip unique field

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert values via a select statement, but I want to skip over some duplicate rows in the source table.  The SELECT portion of the query below produces the rows that I want to insert.  The only hitch is that I don't want to insert the value that I'm DISTINCTing.  How can I take advantage of DISTINCT yet not insert that value?

```
INSERT INTO
    table_dest (field1, field2)
SELECT
    DISTINCT(table_src.id),  -- Don't insert this value!
    table_src.field1,
    table_src.field2
FROM table_src
```

Comment: I don't believe that MySQL is doing what you expect.  The `distinct` keyword is applied to *all* the columns, not just the `id`.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and then the desired result?  It might be easier to see your data to solve the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ah, I didn't know that.  GROUP BY is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` instead:

```
SELECT
    table_src.field1,
    table_src.field2
FROM table_src
GROUP BY table_src.id
```